# How to merge SVN branch to trunk?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, merge, eclipse-plugin

I need to merge branch(SVN) to trunk. we had cut branch from trunk at time T1.  After that development continued on trunk and branch.
Now i want to merge all branch changes to trunk.  What are the steps for it and tool to achieve the same.

Should i take first trunk changes in to branch and then merge branch changes to trunk `or`Should i directly marge branch changes to trunk ?

What is the best tool for achieving the same.  I am using Eclipse, svn, Tortoise SVN client in my project

I am sure there must be some tool like eclipse plugin or some other clientto achieve the same, but if somebody can point me great ones, it would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse, you can use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). When installing the plugin, there is an option to install the CollabNet Merge client that helps resolving conflicts during a merge in case they exist between the branch and the trunk.

Comment: I have installed subclipse with collabnet merge. But how should I collapse branch to trunk now ?

Comment: @emilly You can take a look at the [screenshots](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=rr1TIx) on the project page. Right-click on the trunk project and select Team -> Merge, then follow the instructions.

Comment: I believe if Right-click on the trunk project and select Team -> Merge. First it will bring changes from branch in to working copy(i.e trunk) and then I need to commit those changes in trunk . Right ?

Comment: @emilly Right. If you have conflicts though, say because both the trunk and the branch had changes in the same file, you'd have to resolve them before committing.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ from JetBrains is the best Java IDE on the market.  It has tools for working with Subversion and Git that make this easy.

[BeyondCompare](http://download.cnet.com/Beyond-Compare/3000-2242_4-10015731.html) is a terrific tool.  Maybe that can help you.

Keep it simple - just merge the branch into the trunk and you're done.

The bigger the merge, the harder it is.

Trunk is a convention, but it's just another name for a branch that is given some special status.  Another way to look at it is to simply cut future branches off the one you have.  Tell future developers to check out the latest branch, not trunk.  Just keep going. Forget about trunk.